# Java for loop with an ArrayList

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist

Here is the contents of my ArrayList `contain`

```
HPDH-1,001, Check-out date: 7/7/7

JTI-1,001, Check-out date: 7/7/7
```

My code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < contain.size(); i++) {
    if (contain.get(i).contains(code)) {
        System.out.println(contain.get(i));
    }
}
```

The thing is my variable code was String "JTI-1"
Why isn't it giving me the JTI-1 output?
I am trying to get it to display the value of the variable code.
I want to remove the contain.get(i) if it would just give me the one I typed in.

Comment: "*Why isn't it only giving me the JTI-1 output?*" What's the question here? What is it displaying that you're not expecting?

Comment: please include the output of the code, also make sure you have specified the generic type of the ArrayList as <String>

Comment: try `code.trim()` before using it in `contains` method.

Comment: Fair play for AmitD's magic ability to guess you had a white space in the string you put in your question... Your `code` string was apparently not `"JTI-1"` as you said, since `trim()` solved your problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The code is correct assuming List of strings. `I have not modified any of your source code just to give you idea that it works fine.`

```
    List<String> contain = new ArrayList<String>();
    contain.add("HPDH-1,001, Check-out date: 7/7/7");
    contain.add("JTI-1,001, Check-out date: 7/7/7");
    String code = "JTI-1 ";
    for (int i = 0; i < contain.size(); i++) {
        if (contain.get(i).contains(code.trim())) {<---Use trim it is possible that code may have extra space
            System.out.println(contain.get(i));
        }
    }
```

Comment: do i call 'contain.size()' in every iteration again like this?

Comment: Arraylist size() function just returns the integer value so it wont make any impact. In above answer as I had mentioned I wasn't looking to refactor the code.

Answer (score 14):

I think fundamentally the code is correct. I would check your inputs and make sure they're really what you think.

I would perhaps rewrite your loop as:

```
for (String s : contain) {
   if (s.contains(code)) {
      // found it
   }
}
```

to make use of the object iterators (the above assumes you have an `ArrayList<String>`). And perhaps rename `contain`. It's not very clear what this is.

Answer (score 3):

Your code ist correct, though I would also advise you to make use of iterators:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        ArrayList<String> contain = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("HPDH-1,001, Check-out date: 7/7/7",
                "JTI-1,001, Check-out date: 7/7/7"));

        String code = "JTI";

        // your loop
        for (int i = 0; i < contain.size(); i++) {
            if (contain.get(i).contains(code)) {
                System.out.println(contain.get(i));
            }
        }

        // my suggestion
        for (String s : contain) {
               if (s.contains(code)) {
                  System.out.println(s);
               }
        }
    }
}
```

> Output:
>
> JTI-1,001, Check-out date: 7/7/7
>
> JTI-1,001, Check-out date: 7/7/7

If this output is not what you want, please add more information.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println("Find name");
        String str = s.nextLine();
        List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < surname.size(); i++) {
            if(surname.get(i).equals(str)){
                result.add(i);
            }
        }
        for (Integer integer : result) {
            System.out.println(integer);
        }
```